# which database suits my application mysql or mongodb ? using Node.js , Backbone , Now.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb, backbone.js

I want to make an application like docs.google.com (without its api,completely on my own server) using 
frontend : backbone 
backend : node

What database would u think is better ? mysql or mongodb ? Should support good scalability .
I am familiar with mysql with php and i will be happy if the answer is mysql.
But many tutorials i saw, they used mongodb, why did they use mongodb without mysql ?
What should i use ?

Can anyone give me link for some sample application(with source) build using backbone , Node , mysql (or mongo) . or atleast app. with Node and mysql

Thanks

Answer (score 45, accepted):

With MongoDB, you can just *store* JSON objects and retrieve them fully-formed, so you don't really need an ORM layer and you spend less CPU time translating your data back-and-forth. The developers behind MongoDB have also made horizontally scaling the database a higher priority and let you run arbitrary Javascript code to pre-process data on the DB side (allowing map-reduce style filtering of data).

But you lose some for these gains: You can't join records. Actually, the JSON structure you store could only be done via joins in SQL, but in MongoDB you only have that one structure to your data, while in SQL you can query differently and get your data represented in alternate ways much easier, so if you need to do a lot of analytics on your database, MongoDB will make that harder.

The query language in MongoDB is "rougher", in my opinion, than SQL's, partly because it's less familiar, and partly because the querying features "feel" haphazardly put together, partially to make it valid JSON, and partially because there are literally a couple of ways of doing the same thing, and some are older ways that aren't as useful or regularly-formatted as the others. And there's the added complexity of the array and sub-object types over SQL's simple row-based design, so the syntax has to be able to handle querying for arrays that contain *some* of the values you defined, contain *all* of the values you defined, contain *only* the values you defined, and contain *none* of the values you defined. The same distinctions apply to object keys and their values, and this makes the query syntax harder to grasp. (And while I can see the need for edge-cases, the `$where` query parameter, which takes a javascript function that is run on every record of the data and returns a boolean, is a Siren song because you can easily define what objects you want to return or not, but it has to run on *every* record in the database, no indexes can be used.)

So, it depends on what you want to do, but since you say it's for a Google Docs clone, you *probably* don't care about any representation *but* the document representation, itself, and you're *probably* only going to query based on document ID, document name, or the owner's ID/name, nothing too complex in the querying.

Then, I'd say being able to take the JSON representation of the document your user is editing, and just throw it into the database and have it automatically index these important fields, is worth the price of learning a new database.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your post.  If you want it deleted, you can flag it for moderator involvement and ask them to remove it since you can't as it is accepted.

Answer (score 12):

I was also struggling with this choice looking at the hype created by using MongoDB for tasks it was not built for. So my 2 cents are:

1. Storing and retrieving hierarchical objects, that your documents probably are, is easier in MongoDB, as David says. It becomes more complicated if you want to store documents that are bigger than 16Mb though - MongoDB's answer is GridFS.
2. Organising documents in folders, groups, keeping track of which user owns which documents and who he/she provided access to them is definitely easier with MySQL - you have the advantage of powerful SQL queries with joins etc., built in EXPLAIN optimization, triggers, functions, stored procedures, etc. MongoDB is nowhere near.

So what prevents you from using both MySQL to organize the documents and MongoDB to store one collection of documents identified by id (or several collections - one for each document type)? It seems to me the best choice and using two databases in one application is not a problem, really.

MySQL will store users, groups, folders, permissions - whatever you fancy - and for each document it will store a reference to the collection and the document id (MongoDB has a special format for it - DBRefs). MongoDB will store documents themselves in collections, if they are all less than 16MB, or the previews and metadata of documents in collections and the whole documents in GridFS.

Comment: I have done an approach like this for a project that involved secure transactions, and user permissions on mysql and complex documents on mongo, and it's totally doable. But for future reference, the mysql team is adding json as a field type on the next version. worth looking into it for these kind of scenarios.

Answer (score 9):

David provided a good answer. A few things to add to it.

1. MongoDB's flexible nature permits for easy agile / iterative development.
2. MongoDB like node.js is asyncronous in nature and works very well within asyncronous environments.
3. Mongoose is a good ODM (object document mapper) that makes working with MongoDB with Node.js feel very natural. Unlike ORMs this is a very thin layer.

For Google Doc like functionality, the flexibility & very rich data structure provided by MongoDB feels like a much better fit.

You can find some good example posts by searching for mongoose, node and MongoDB.

Here's one that also uses backbone.js and looks good http://mattkopala.com/blog/2012/02/12/getting-started-with-nodejs/